# How to interpret API documentation?

Tags: api

Ok this might sound like a stupid question, but I've looked at so many different API's for different websites and they say something like "make a GET request to ...", but it will only give part of the URL. What am I missing here? Where am I meant to get the information I need if I only have part of the URL?

An example I found recently is the one for Discord.

[image]

I need to make a GET request, fair enough, but to where?

Again probably just me being stupid, but I'm curious.

Comment: I think that you want to make a GET request on the Base URL of the service + /users/[user_id]. Better look up how the id formatted and how you get it - mostly you get an JSON object back as the answer. For example: GET on example.com/users/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to have a server running the application or at least middleware which will serve up API routes.

Common examples would be a node with express, C# web API's in .NET, etc.

Essentially you set up routing on the backend so that when you call an API on your web application it matches the route and then you can perform things like query database etc.

I would highly recommend looking into node with express.

What stack are you using?
This should get you going
https://www.fullstackpython.com/api-creation.html

You basically need to set up some basic route operations running on a python server and stance and then you would point your API calls to the port where the instance is running using the same domain if you wish.

I highly recommend looking into web services and crud operations

Comment: I updated my answer as best I could if it helps you please accept it thank you very much.